# Variable always equal to 0 in my ode model

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations, desolve

I have written an ODE model in R using the `ode()` function from the `deSolve` package. The equation predicts the evolution of the mass of pesticide on foliar surface. `app1` is equal to the pesticide's mass applied (on day 156) and the function should track the evolution of the toxicant. However, I noticed that the output for the variable `mf` (foliar mass) is always equal to 0, even though it should be changing over time (fram the day 156). I am not sure what is causing this issue. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
library(deSolve)

mod <- function(t, yini, param, Precip) {   
  app1 <- ifelse(t == 156, 1.12, 0)
  jgrow <- 32
  igrow <- ifelse(t >= 136 & t < 169, t - 136, ifelse(t > 168, 0.9, ifelse(t < 136, 0, NA)))
  cover <- 0.9 * igrow / jgrow
  P = Precip[t]
  
  with(as.list(c(yini, param)), { 
    
    mharv = ifelse(t== 201, mf, 0)
    
    
    d_MF <- (app1 * sa * (1-drift)*cover*sa)- (mf* exp(-kf*dt)) + (yf * (mf* exp(-kf*dt))) - mf * (1-exp(-fet * P * dt)) - mharv
    return(list(c(d_MF))) 
    
  })} 

params <- list(drift = 0.1, dt = 1, kf = 0.023, sa = 32.4, fet = 0.2, yf = 0.6)
t <- seq(1, 365, by = 1)
Precip=rep(0, 365)
Precip[155:205] =c(0, 0.96, 0.71, 0, 0, 0.08, 14.99, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 3.66, 0, 0.13, 0, 5.28, 0.03, 0, 0, 3.15, 0.84, 1.83, 0.03, 0, 2.29, 0, 0, 0.15, 1.65, 0, 0.91, 0.18, 2.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.17, 0.1, 0, 1.45, 0.25, 0, 0.03, 0.46, 0.03, 0)
y0 <- c(mf = 0)
sol <- ode(y = y0, times = t, func = mod, parms = params, Precip = Precip)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a part of a solution. The time was rounded with `floor` and `precip` converted to a forcing function with constant interpolation.

The `igrow <- ifelse(...)`-function looks strange anyway, especially as a value in the model should never be NA.

```r
library(deSolve)

mod <- function(t, yini, param, f_precip) {   
  app1 <- ifelse(floor(t) == 156, 1.12, 0)   # use round, floor or trunc
  jgrow <- 32
  
  ## the following can also be converted to a forcing function
  ## but I suspect it may have some errors
  igrow <- ifelse(t >= 136 & t < 169, t - 136, ifelse(t > 168, 0.9, ifelse(t < 136, 0, NA)))
  
  cover <- 0.9 * igrow / jgrow
  P <- f_precip(t)
  
  with(as.list(c(yini, param)), { 
    mharv <- ifelse(floor(t) == 201, mf, 0) # use floor, trunc or round
    d_MF <- (app1 * sa * (1 - drift) * cover * sa) - (mf * exp(-kf * dt)) + 
            (yf * (mf * exp(-kf * dt))) - mf * (1 - exp(-fet * P * dt)) - mharv
    return(list(c(d_MF))) 
  })
} 

params <- list(drift = 0.1, dt = 1, kf = 0.023, sa = 32.4, fet = 0.2, yf = 0.6)

t <- seq(1, 365, by = 1)
Precip <- rep(0, 365)
Precip[155:205] <- c(0, 0.96, 0.71, 0, 0, 0.08, 14.99, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.1, 
                     0, 3.66, 0, 0.13, 0, 5.28, 0.03, 0, 0, 3.15, 0.84, 1.83, 0.03, 
                     0, 2.29, 0, 0, 0.15, 1.65, 0, 0.91, 0.18, 2.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                     3.17, 0.1, 0, 1.45, 0.25, 0, 0.03, 0.46, 0.03, 0)

## define a forcing function by tabular interpolation
f_precip <- approxfun(t, Precip, method = "constant", rule = 2)

y0 <- c(mf = 0)
sol <- ode(y = y0, times = t, func = mod, parms = params, 
           f_precip = f_precip)

plot(sol)
```

[image: solution of the ode]

### Edit

To answer the comment of the OP, why "the function reaches its maximum on day 2 after application", we can apply the following modifications:

I the model function, replace `app1` as follows. It is also a good idea to add some internal variables as extra outputs in `return` after the `c()` of the state vector.

```
mod <- function(t, yini, param, f_precip, f_app) {   
  #app1 <- ifelse(floor(t) == 156, 1.12, 0)
  app1 <- f_app(t)
    .....
    return(list(c(d_MF), P = P, app = app1, igrow=igrow))
  })
}
```

Then define a new forcing:

```r
f_app <- approxfun(c(0, 156,        156+1/24, 365),
                   c(0, 1.12 * 24,    0,        0), method="constant", rule=2)
```

We see that only the relevant time steps are needed.

The call to `ode` must then be modified to contain the new forcing. And it is very important to reduce the time step, so that the external forcing is not overlooked by the automatic step size algorithm of the solver. It can be done by setting smaller time steps in the `t`-vector or by an additional argument `hmax`.

```r
sol <- ode(y = y0, times = t, func = mod, parms = params, 
           f_precip = f_precip, f_app = f_app, hmax=1/24)

plot(sol, mfrow=c(2, 2))
```

A small time step, however, slows down the simulation. To avoid this, the event mechanism can be used. Then you have to re-formulate the model that it does not contain `app1` in the derivative, but instead calculate the effect of it on `mf`. It is then directly and instantaneously added to `mf` at the event time.

[image: simulation with extra outputs]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was very helpful. However, I see that the function reaches its maximum on day 2 after application, whereas it would be reasonable for the maximum values to be reached on the application date. Can you suggest an explanation or a solution to this problem?

Comment: It occurs because the application takes place during the full day. ODE models are defined as derivatives and then integrated over time. If you want a shorter time step, you have two choices: either implement it as event, to force an instantaneous change of state variables, or to divide the application and the time step by a constant. If the time unit is "1 day", a one-hour application would then be 1.12 / (1/24) = 1.12*24. The forcing function must then also be simplified to contain the only the desired time period. This could be another SO question.

Answer (score 2):

`app1` and `mharv` are practically always zero, the slope function is almost certainly never evaluated at this specific points, and even if it were, this single-point spike will only have negligible influence.

For the same reason, `t` almost certainly never being an integer in the call to `mod`, you should get an error when trying to use `t` as integer index, but perhaps that gets automatically truncated.

So in the end, every term in the derivative expression has a factor that is zero, making the zero function the correct solution.

Comment: The problem is that I want to observe the degradation of the compound. That is, the maximum mass will be at app1 and it should degrade as the days go by. However, with this solution, I cannot predict the degradation curve.

Comment: You could replace `t` in the places where it should be an integer with `floor(t)` or `round(t)` to get a non-trivial influence of these impulses.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on this? Do you mean in the P = Precip[t] line?

Comment: Also where you compare to integers. So you could define the integer `nt`, or so, once to use in the 3 places. // How certain are you about the scalar state? You are describing two observables, the plant mass and the compound, should the state not have at least two components?

Comment: An `if` or `ifelse` in a model function is seldom a good idea. This was discussed several times here at StackOverflow. Instead it is in most cases better to use forcing functions or events. More about this can be found [here](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html) and in the deSolve help files about [forcings](https://rdrr.io/rforge/deSolve/man/forcings.html) and events.